# installing NASM on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, nasm, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to linux and want to run an assembly language program using ubuntu 11.10.
The installation failed showing the following message

```
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
mplayer-skins mplayer libggi2 libgii1 libgii1-target-x youtube-dl
Use ‘apt-get autoremove’ to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nasm
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1557kB of archives.
After unpacking 2855kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/onieric/main nasm i386 2.09.081 could
not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'.
failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nasm/nasm-2.09.08-1-i386.deb
could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
--fix -missing?
```

I am unable to figure out what the problem exactly is??
i would like to mention that i have been using ubuntu through a Live CD and not as an installed OS.

Comment: You should ask this question here: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have problems with your internet connection. Specifically dns resolution. Check your /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Specifically he has a problem with domain name resolution. Check your DNS configuration. Does browsing the WWW work?